# how to read mac address of cellphone thats unavailable in android studio

Tags: android, macos, android-wifi, mac-address, wifimanager

I have written some codes in android studio  and I Can Read the Mac address but the problem is when the mac address of  Cellphone is Unavailble  an blutooth address is Unavailble too .... so What Can I read Mac address in this situation ?

Comment: I can not understand your question. Do you want to read mac address of your phone?

Comment: yeah. but in my cellphone is unavailble!!!!  but it exists

Comment: it means your device have mac address but it is not show ?

Comment: please correct me or elaborate your problem

Comment: It means my device have mac address but it is not show

Comment: what is your device name or device android version

Comment: htc and android version is : 4.1.2